# what is tool like TortoiseSVN(Windows) on ubuntu?

Tags: svn, ubuntu, tortoisesvn

what is tool like TortoiseSVN on ubuntu? please help me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/), it is actually inspired by TortoiseSVN:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try Syncro SVN Client
[Syncro SVN Client](http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/)

Comment: perfect replace for tortise SVN for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try the nautilus-script-collection-svn package. Once it is installed, do
Code:

nautilus-script-manager enable Subversion

to enable the scripts for your user. When you right-click files you should now have a new menu entry: Script -> Subversion.